# Use assigned array in foreach with variable name in smarty

Tags: php, variables, foreach, smarty

I assigned an array in my PHP program, the name of this smarty variable is variable,

```
while ($order=mysql_fetch_object($orderQuery){
   while ($res = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
      $smarty->append("v".$order->id,$res);
   }
   $smarty->append("order",$order);
}
```

and then in my `.tpl` file I use this code :

```
{foreach $order as $o}
   Order id is : {$o->id}
   {foreach $v|cat:$o->id as $a}
      <a href="#">{$a->name}</a>
   {/foreach}
   <br />
{/foreach}
```

The `$o` work without any problem and I can show order id but inner `foreach` not work and I didn't get any error !

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the right way :-)

I should use variable variables in smarty so I changed my template to this:

```
{foreach $order as $o}
   Order id is : {$o->id}
   {assign vo 'v'|cat:$o->id}
   {foreach ${$vo} as $a}
      <a href="#">{$a->name}</a>
   {/foreach}
   <br />
{/foreach}
```